# Selection of Continued filled Cells and Calculation of MAX,MIN,AVG

Tags: excel, vba

[image]Hope You are all Safe
I'm trying to calculate MAX, MIN and AVG Values of filled cells which are continued without blank cell (As you can see it in the left side of the sample image ).
I'm facing problem in selecting these randomly placed cells and calculate the above values and also "From" and "To" values of respective range.
Please let me know how to do it. So far I've constructed following code

```
    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim destSht As Worksheet

    Set destSht = Worksheets("Final")

   With Worksheets("Source")   
   lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   For Each Cel In .Range("C2:C" & lastrow)
   If .Cells(Cel.Row, "C") <> "" Then
    Cel.Offset(0, -1).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)    
   'It will give "From" Column

   '' Plz suggest for "To" Column

   Range("G5").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-4]:R[4]C[-4])"    'It will give values "MAX" Column
   Range("H5").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(RC[-5]:R[4]C[-5])"    'It will give values "MIN" Column
   Range("I5").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-6]:R[4]C[-6])"  'It will give values "AVG" Column

   End If
   Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some quick, which should work.
I don't know what you want to do in the "Final" worksheet, so haven't focused on that line.

Logic is to have one big loop (`For i...`) that go through the whole Column C. When a value is found in column C (`If .Cells(i, "C") <> "" Then`), we perform a "small loop" (`For j = i To lastrow + 1`) to check next empty cell to decide the "small group" range. When that range is decided we perform the `To`, `From`, `MAX`, `MIN` and `AVG` formulas, which has to be dynamic.

```
Option Explicit

Sub trial()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim destSht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long


Set destSht = Worksheets("Final")

With Worksheets("Source")
lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow + 1 'loop whole range (column C)
        If .Cells(i, "C") <> "" Then 'If column C is not empty then
            For j = i To lastrow + 1 'Loop "group" range to find next empty cell. Start from current loop i to last row and add one row to get to next empty cell.
                If .Cells(j, "C") = "" Then 'When next empty cell is found (i.e. end of small group range) then apply formulas
                    .Cells(i, "E").Value = .Cells(i, "B").Value 'From
                    .Cells(i, "F").Value = .Cells(j - 1, "B").Value 'To
                    .Cells(i, "G").Formula = "=MAX(C" & i & ":C" & j - 1 & ")" 'MAX
                    .Cells(i, "H").Formula = "=MIN(C" & i & ":C" & j - 1 & ")" 'MIN
                    .Cells(i, "I").Formula = "=AVERAGE(C" & i & ":C" & j - 1 & ")" 'AVG
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Wizhi...Its works like a charm.....Can you please let me know how to skip after getting result in the first row only (As you can see it in the left side of Sample image in yellow color)....Basically I Don't require values after getting first row of every range

Comment: Got the Answer through another post ....Replaced ... If .Cells(i, "C") <> ""  ...with ...If .Cells(i, "C") <> "" And .Cells(i - 1, "C") = ""...........Thanks again @Wizhi

Comment: Glad it helped a bit. You were faster to answer, but yes, that's a simple and good solution if you only want the first row. Happy coding :).